# gnu-radio on Ubuntu 20.04 and AIS processing seems impossible

Tags: gnuradio

I have searched, installed, and tried every package there is to get AIS processing using the gnu-radio companion to no avail.

I tried installing gnu-radio both with conda and apt on Ubuntu 20.04. The conda way raises issues when I try to install gr-ais; doing it the "apt install" the modules do not show up on gnuradio-companion. I tried finding the GNUradio Bootable Live CD online, could not find it. I tried several other AIS related repos claiming to work with gnuradio, to no avail once again.

I have an STL-SDR dongle. At least I got that to work.

So, the question is: if I want to process AIS using GNUradio 3.8(latest) on ubuntu 20.04, how can I do that? What packages/modules/environment are the appropriate ones to use?

Thank you.

Comment: I use `rtl-ais` the easiest is to add a PPA and install. `sudo add-apt-repository -n ppa:openplotter/openplotter` and `sudo apt install rtl-ais`

Comment: That sounds like an answer @Jean-Marie!  In my opinion you should create an answer that says the same thing, but flesh it out a bit more, and then delete the comment.  [Comments aren't for answering the question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), and you can get reputation points for answers ;)

Comment: @rclocher3 I am asking how to do this using gnuradio, @Marie’s comment is not an answer. A third party software that does not use gnuradio, or gnuradio-companion, is not an answer.